# PCMサンプリング機能とSDHCI USB MSCを同時に機能させたい。

Tags: spresense, audio

題記のトライのため、

1. サンプルスケッチ : UsbMscAndFileOperationのLine 19 ~ Line 25を改造

```c
#include <Audio.h>
#include <SDHCI.h>
SDClass SD;
AudioClass *theAudio;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  theAudio = AudioClass::getInstance();
  delay(100);
  theAudio->begin();
```

2. 実行し、ターミナルに表示された"Finish USB MSC? (y/n)"に対して"y"を入力すると、以下のメッセージが出力

```
21:52:44.492 -> up_assert: Assertion failed at file:components/capture/capture_component.cpp line: 801 task: capture0
21:52:44.492 -> up_registerdump: R0: 00000001 0d04e558 000000e0 0d050910 0d04e558 0d065108 0d051068 0d05be58
21:52:44.492 -> up_registerdump: R8: 0d0384df 00000321 0d0647c0 00000000 00000000 0d065108 0d01a395 0d01a958
21:52:44.492 -> up_registerdump: xPSR: 61000000 BASEPRI: 000000e0 CONTROL: 00000004
21:52:44.492 -> up_registerdump: EXC_RETURN: ffffffe9
21:52:44.531 -> up_dumpstate: sp:     0d065108
```

3. 別のトライから、トリガーは`theAudio->begin()`以後の`SD.endUsbMsc()`のようだが、メッセージは"capture"で出ている

この様子からすると、Audio機能とMSC機能は相性が悪いようですが、うまく折り合い付けられるでしょうか？

希望の機能は、USB2本をPCにつなげて、録音が終わって生成されたWAVファイルをPCからそのまま引きとりたいです。また録音機能は、コマンドでFFTの結果出力機能と切り替えられるようにしたいです(AS_CODECTYPE_PCM <-> AS_CODECTYPE_WAV) 。

アドバイスいただけると助かります。

Comment: 1)に書かれている内容(UsbMscAndFileOperation.inoにtheAudio->beginを追加)を試してみましたが、2)のAssertionは特に発生せず。質問内容に書き漏れていることはありませんか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。無いと思っておりますが、念の為、確認のお時間をください。

Comment: 再度、上記のコードで再現を試みましたが(”theAudio->begin();”の有効・無効を切り替え)、発生しなくなりました。理由は判然としませんが、折り合い付けられそうな気がしてきました。本件は一旦Closeにさせてください。ありがとうございました。